# Parameter for "Delete" post method has blank attributes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm having an issue in my MVC application (for making basic CRUD changes to a database) where the object parameter getting passed to my "Delete" post method has blank parameters, even though the object returned by the get method is correct.  As a result, when I try to delete the object from the database I get the following exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entity
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.RuntimeFailureMethods.Requires(Boolean condition, String userMessage, String conditionText)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Remove(TEntity entity)
   at MvcApplication1.HomeController.Delete(ISBN bookToDelete) in C:\Users\MMcCrimmon\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MortonPublishingDatabaseInterface\MvcApplication1\Controllers\HomeController.vb:line 103
```

After a bit of digging I found this question: [Missing something in "Delete" post method in MVC (EF 4.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485131/missing-something-in-delete-post-method-in-mvc-ef-4-1), which seems to be identical, but the answers there did not resolve my problem.  What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my controller code:

```vb
' GET: /Home/Delete/5

Function Delete(ByVal id As String) As ActionResult
    Dim bookToDelete = _db.ISBNs.Find(id)
    Return View(bookToDelete)
End Function

' POST: /Home/Delete/5

<HttpPost()> _
Function Delete(bookToDelete As ISBN) As ActionResult
    Dim originalBook = _db.ISBNs.Find(bookToDelete.Product_Code)
    Try
        _db.ISBNs.Remove(originalBook)
        _db.SaveChanges()

        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    Catch exc As Exception
        Return View(originalBook)
    End Try
End Function
```

and here's the view for the Delete page:

```razor
@ModelType MvcApplication1.ISBN

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Delete"
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"
End Code

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<p/>
<fieldset>
    <legend>ISBN</legend>

    <div class="display-label">
        <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Product_Code)</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.Product_Code)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
        <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Title)</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
        <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.ISBN_UPC)</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.ISBN_UPC)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
        <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.ManualName)</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.ManualName)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
        <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.PgCount)</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.PgCount)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
        <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.BookSize)</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.BookSize)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
        <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.ColorOrBW)</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.ColorOrBW)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
        <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.PageCount)</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.PageCount)
    </div>
</fieldset>
@Using Html.BeginForm()
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @<p>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
End Using
```

Following the answer for [Missing something in "Delete" post method in MVC (EF 4.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485131/missing-something-in-delete-post-method-in-mvc-ef-4-1), here's the modified view (still doesn't work):

```razor
@ModelType MvcApplication1.ISBN

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Delete"
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"
End Code

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<p/>
@Using Html.BeginForm()
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @<fieldset>
        <legend>ISBN</legend>

        <div class="display-label">
            <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Product_Code)</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.Product_Code)
        </div>

        <div class="display-label">
            <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Title)</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="display-label">
            <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.ISBN_UPC)</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.ISBN_UPC)
        </div>

        <div class="display-label">
            <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.ManualName)</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.ManualName)
        </div>

        <div class="display-label">
            <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.PgCount)</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.PgCount)
        </div>

        <div class="display-label">
            <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.BookSize)</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.BookSize)
        </div>

        <div class="display-label">
            <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.ColorOrBW)</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.ColorOrBW)
        </div>

        <div class="display-label">
            <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.PageCount)</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.PageCount)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    @<p>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
End Using
```

Full disclosure: I'm new to MVC, ASP, *and* VB.NET, so please forgive me if I'm making some rookie mistake here...

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on your delete method? If it does not fire then try hitting F12 prior to delete with network inspection on. There is an exception somewhere either in returning to the client of the rendering of the client itself. What do your Delete http post parameters look like?

Comment: @Irb The bookToDelete parameter in my Delete http post method is passed and appears to be a valid ISBN object, but its parameters (e.g., Product_Code) are all blank, so the Find method on the DB is returning a null value.  That is, `bookToDelete.Product_Code = ""`, so `originalBook = Nothing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be passing the "bookToDelete" parameter through to the DELETE method.  In fact you shouldn't be passing this through as it's an object not a simple value.  I would pass the "book id" through on delete post action (same as delete get action)

Altering the delete view form code by adding the following line between the @Using Html.BeginForm() and End Using lines

`@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)`

And change the DELETE post method in your controller to

`Function Delete(id as string) As ActionResult`

Dim originalBook = _db.ISBNs.Find(id)

Comment: Quick note: I had to add another parameter to the Delete post method to keep it from having the same signature as the get method, so the final post signature looks like this: `Function Delete(id As String, FormCollection As Collection) As ActionResult`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a  to your form indicating the parameter to pass to your controller.
E.g. If your controller is using "BookToDeleteID" as parameter name, your view html should look like this:

```
<form>
    ......
    <input type="hidden" name="BookToDeleteID" value="A_NUMBER"/>
    <input type="submit" value="delete"/>
</form>
```

Sometimes it has weird cases where you have to pass JSON objects to controllers. Maybe it's a data integrity concern by Microsoft. So I guess you have to parse the entire model for all actions.